# PHP Place text (title) before each array category

Tags: php, arrays

This function is supposed to echo all singles and doubles numbers. (eg. 01 - 01 02).

I am trying to place a title before each 'category' using the code below and it is not working properly.

It should be something like this

SINGLES

01,02,03

DOUBLES

01 02, 03 04, 05 06

Can you help me fix this? Thanks!

```
function check_stats($todas){

    $arrlength = count($todas);



    for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {


        $arrlength2 = count($todas[$x]);

        if($arrlength2==1){

            echo 'single'.'</br></br>';

            list($a) = explode(" ", implode(" ", $todas[$x]));  

            echo $a; echo '</br>';

        }   

        if($arrlength2==2){

            echo 'double'.'</br></br>';

            list($a,$b) = explode(" ", implode(" ", $todas[$x]));  

            echo $a.' '.$b; echo '</br>';

        }   

    } //for

} //function
```

Comment: Where is category?

Comment: Thanks @AliFarhoudi. They are after each IF condition. (as 'single' and 'double')

Comment: I have just edited the question. Thanks @AliFarhoudi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to separate singles and doubles. And you want to print them separately. You can't print them separately while you haven't detected them all. Then you need to detect all categories and after that you can print them separately. To do this you should save categories on detection and after detection print saved categories.

```
function check_stats($todas){
    $singles = array(); // an array to save single numbers
    $doubles = array(); // an array so save doubles

    foreach ($todas as $toda) { // cleaner and beautifier than for
        if (count($toda) == 1) { // direct compare without extra $arrlength2
            $singles[] = $toda[0]; // will push $toda[0] to $singles array
        } else if (count($toda) == 2) { // when put else compares less
            $doubles[] = $toda[0] . ' ' . $toda[1];
        }
    }

    // then you can do whatever with $singles and $doubles

    echo 'SINGLES' . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($singles as $single) {
        echo $single . PHP_EOL;
    }

    echo 'DOUBLES' . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($doubles as $double) {
        echo $double . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

**Edit #1**:
If there were more than 2 kind of variables, then you can keep them in an array.

```
function check_stats($todas){
    $result_array = array();

    foreach ($todas as $toda) {
        $result_array[count($toda)] = implode(' ', $toda);
        // the above code will save each single or double or triple or etc
        // in an index in their size
    }

    return $result_array; // better return it and use out of function
}

$result = check_stats($todas);
// now print them
foreach ($todas as $key => $toda) {
    echo $key . PHP_EOL; // print count (that is index)
    foreach ($toda as $t) {
        echo $t . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if there is singles, doubles, triples... to infinite?

Comment: I mean. Could be singles and doubles or more.